# Viewing Stored Images in Azure Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have images that are stored in Blobs in Azure. Now I want to display them on a website. What would be the easiest way to display these images ?

Comment: If the answer below works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each blob has its own Url which you can retrieve from the Azure Portal or by using the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

You could save the Urls in your database and display them directly on your website like you would any other image Url.

If your web site requires a CDN, you could add an Azure CDN on top of your blob storage [Like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SAS (shared access signature). it's short lived url and gives ability to view image for certian period. you can also provide permissions at granular level.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change the blob container Public access level to Blob or container, then you can visit all the images in the container via link like "`https://your_storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/your_container_name/your_image.JPG`".

You can follow steps below:

1.In azure portal, nav to your storage account -> select the container which stores your image -> change the Public Access Level:

[image]

2.After set public access level, then you can use this link I mentioned above to visit your image. In your case, you can just put this link to your website.

[image]